# Listening for textfield events

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a square movieclip on stage. I am trying to set the dimensions of the square by entering the dimension of the side from the textfield(Input text).

The name of the movieClip is square_mc and the textfield is side_txt

I want to change the dimension of the square when the value is entered in side_txt and ENTER key is pressed.

So for which event of the textfield should I listen.

How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownListener);

function keyDownListener(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
  if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
  {
    square_mc.width = square_mc.height = int(side_txt.text());
  }
}
```

Comment: but wouldn't that listen for keypresses even when not in the textfield?

Answer (score 1):

[`textInput`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#event%3atextInput) event might work. Just check for the key pressed in the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

[`Event.CHANGE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#event%3achange) dispatched by textfield (for every entered character) or [`KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#KEY_DOWN) with check if enter was pressed dispatched by parent `DisplayObject`